# Good file format for dumping and comparing large amounts of structured data

Tags: database, data-analysis, data, diff

I'm on the lookout for a suitable file format and a comparison tool that my organization can use to compare large amounts of structured data. The data in question comes from an object-oriented database. We have tools that dump the contents of all objects in a database into a text file. We then run the standard diff tool to compare the dumps. We do this comparison to ensure that new code in our software doesn't introduce unexplained data for a given problem. Our typical database is large and the objects in the database are their component data is heterogenous and often times are in the form of lengthy arrays. Therefore, when we run the standard diff tool to compare these database dumps, we have difficulty in quickly determining what a particular diff really means: which object is different? what member data of the object in question is different?

Below is a snippet from one of our dump files:

```
Object 1
  Attribute 1
    5
    6
    7
    8
    .
    . <100s of lines>
    .
    500
```

If I'm comparing two such lengthy dump files and I see that one of the numbers in the section above that I have annotated with "<100s of lines>" is different between the two files, then I want to be able to quickly say that "Object 1" is the differing object and "Attribute 1" is the differing attribute.

So my question is what format for the dump file would be conducive for this kind of smart diff and what comparison tools are out there that do these kinds of smart comparisons.

Comment: This question can be on-topic here if you adjust it a bit to focus on the comparison tools instead of the file format.

Comment: @RockPaperLizard: My thinking is the formats and the tools might be closely related. For example, if there is an awesome JSON diff utility that does exactly what my stated goals above are, then the data format obviously needs to be JSON.

Comment: I would say JSON, although you might go for XML, but it would probably better to completely define the requirements, then find an app or library that fulfils them and go with whichever data format it supports.

Personally, I would knock up a custom Python program to do exactly what is needed.

Comment: Is the order of items important? E.g. in INI-Files, it isn't, in JSON also not. But if you have a list, the order of a list may be important, because things are done first, seconds, ...